# Jquery Ajax Soap Request Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I have tried for different source to solve my issue. but didnt got the solution to my problem.

I am having the webservice on our local network 113. I am in need to use that on other server. both are in same network.

```
POST /GeoMapsMirror/MapService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.1.113
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SP_GetDiversion_Details"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SP_GetDiversion_Details xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Code>string</Code>
    </SP_GetDiversion_Details>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Jquery

```
var SoapMessageInXML = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '<soap:Body>';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '<SP_GetDiversion_Details xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '<Code>'+userid+'</Code>';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '</SP_GetDiversion_Details>';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '</soap:Body>';
            SoapMessageInXML = SoapMessageInXML + '</soap:Envelope>';

            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.support.cors = true;

            valurl = 'http://172.16.1.113/GeoMapsMirror/MapService.asmx?op=SP_GetDiversion_Details'
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: SoapMessageInXML,
            url: valurl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            //contentType: "text/plain",
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(xml) {
                alert(xml)
            },
            error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        console.log("error " + textStatus);
                                        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
                                        if(textStatus == 'timeout')
                                        {     
                                             //alert('Failed from timeout');    
                                             LoadDiversionDtl3()
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            var err = jqXHR.responseText
                                            var n=err.indexOf(",");
                                            var m=err.indexOf(":");
                                            alert(err.substring(m,n))
                                        }
                            }
        });


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I got the error as Invalid HTTP status code 403

I am already stuck for more than 2 day. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `jQuery.support.cors = true;` — That overrides jQuery's automatic detection of CORS support in a browser. The only think you can achieve with that is less useful errors if the browser doesn't support CORS. Don't do that. (The line after where `$` is used instead of jQuery does exactly the same thing, remove that too).

Answer (score 0):

After Multiple changes I have found the answer.It works after removing "contentType" tag on jquery.

```js
valurl = 'http://172.16.1.113/GeoMapsMirror/MapService.asmx/SP_GetDiversion_Details?code='+userid
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: valurl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(xml) {
                document.getElementById('Spcontentdiv').innerHTML = xml.documentElement.textContent;
            },
            error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        console.log("error " + textStatus);
                                        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
        });
```